# How to use a function in onclick that was declared inside window.onload?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        function b(){c();}
    }
    function c(){alert('');}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="b()">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Q1 :** I want to access function b() on click event of button in body tag.
**Q2 :** I want to access function c() from function b() within window.onload.

Comment: Q1 is not posibble this way; Q2 should be no problem if you can run `b`.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why not just execute `c()` on button click?  In any event you don't have an easy way to get at `b()` as it's in the scope of the anonymous function that is the `unload` handler. I think you'd be better off trying to explain the behavior you want not your attempted solution to it.  For example, "how can I run the same code on load AND when a button is clicked?" if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you explain anonymous function definition and also unload handler mean.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : I want to access function b() on click event of button in body tag.

That's fine, you just need to be able to access it. `onclick="b()"` is the same as `onclick="window.b()"` so that obviously won't work the way it is. You can either make `window.b` evaluate to the correct function or establish the event programatically from code.

Q2 : I want to access function c() from function b() within window.onload.

That's fine, and it already works that way.